# Apps Script to Parse core DB

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, parse-platform

I am trying to write from apps script to Parse Core, but I am encountering issues with the class parameter in the below link.

https://script.google.com/macros/library/d/MxhsVzdWH6ZQMWWeAA9tObPxhMjh3Sh48/12

Where do I find the class parameter so I can write to parse core?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The *class* parameter is just the name of the Parse Data class you want to access.

In your Parse.com Dashboard your app's classes are listed on the left (see image below)

[image: example of Parse.com data classes in the GUI]